# Setup JIRA Mylyn connector for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to install the JIRA plugin for Eclipse but I get this error:

```
Problems occurred while performing installation: Operation details
Operation details
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
Software being installed: Atlassian JIRA Connector (Recommended) 3.0.8.v20130328 (com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.jira.feature.group 3.0.8.v20130328)
Software currently installed: SpringSource Tool Suite (required) 2.8.1.201111221000-RELEASE (com.springsource.sts.feature.group 2.8.1.201111221000-RELEASE)
Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
Mylyn Commons UI 3.6.1.v20110720-0100 (org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui 3.6.1.v20110720-0100)
Mylyn Commons UI 3.8.0.v20120612-0600 (org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui 3.8.0.v20120612-0600)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Atlassian Connector for Eclipse UI Commons 3.0.8.v20130328 (com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.commons.ui 3.0.8.v20130328)
To: bundle org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.workbench 0.0.0
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Atlassian JIRA Connector (Recommended) 3.0.8.v20130328 (com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.jira.feature.group 3.0.8.v20130328)
To: com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.commons.ui [3.0.8.v20130328]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: SpringSource Tool Suite (required) 2.8.1.201111221000-RELEASE (com.springsource.sts.feature.group 2.8.1.201111221000-RELEASE)
To: org.springframework.ide.eclipse.mylyn.feature.feature.group [2.8.1,3.0.0)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Mylyn Commons UI 3.8.0.v20120612-0600 (org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.workbench 3.8.0.v20120612-0600)
To: bundle org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui 3.8.0
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Spring IDE Mylyn Integration 2.8.1.201111220115-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.mylyn 2.8.1.201111220115-RELEASE)
To: package org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.provisional.commons.ui 0.0.0
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Spring IDE Mylyn Integration (optional) 2.8.1.201111220115-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.mylyn.feature.feature.group 2.8.1.201111220115-RELEASE)
To: org.springframework.ide.eclipse.mylyn [2.8.1.201111220115-RELEASE]
```

What can I do to work around this issue? I'm using Eclipse Indigo release.

Version: Indigo Release
Build id: 20110615-0604

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to install an incompatible version of Mylyn into an old version of STS/Eclipse. It looks like you have the Juno update site (or the mylyn update site for Juno) in your list of update sites.  You need to remove this and ensure that the Indigo update site is available.